# Is there another term for "weighted keys"?

Tags: keyboard

I am looking for an electric keyboard online and I've found that the "weighted key" part is notmentioned in the detail specs. Is there another term for this?

For example, in [here](http://www.bestbuy.ca/en-CA/product/casio-casio-61-key-keyboard-ctk1100bb-ctk1100bb/10326590.aspx?path=b7460ccda91cc6521a22653a184a0349en02) the only information I found useful regarding this keyboard were its dimension, the # of keys, weight of the entire keyboard and the velocity sensitivity. But it doesn't list whether the keys are weighted or not.

Comment: If it doesn't say weighted keys it likely doesn't have them.

Comment: @MatthewRead, can you 'feel" if the keys are weighted if the keyboard isn't plugged in?

Comment: That depends how familiar you are with what an acoustic piano feels like. In any case, a "cheap" hammer weighted keyboard won't feel quite the same - but if you get a keyboard manufactured by specialist company like Fatar, which only makes keyboards, not complete instruments, you can get pretty close. (The top-of-the-range instruments from Korg, Roland, etc use Fatar keyboards, not their own brands!) A velocity sensitive but non-weighted keyboard feels pretty much like you are just pushing against a spring - nothing like an acoustic piano.

Comment: @alephzero, yeah my family used to own a real one, even a baby grand one. I know by sight to dismiss any flat keyboards bars because they obviously do not carry any weight. Some of the full bar keyboards I've touched felt lighter than a real one piano key, but I don't know if that was just because the key wasn't producing sound made me misjudged. I don't know if a keyboard can even posses the same weight as a real piano key and no I m obviously asking to be as good as a real piano.

Comment: Link is dead, but not essential to question.

Answer (score 4):

If the web site doesn't say "weighted keys", assume they are not weighted!

In any case, there is very little chance you will find a weighted keyboard with a price tag of $120 - unless it's a second-hand keyboard and either it's broken, or its owner is clueless about what it's worth.

Sometimes the term "hammer action" is used instead of "weighted," as in [this Casio](http://www.casio.co.uk/products/electronic-musical-instruments/privia-digital-pianos/product/?v=PX-160BKK5) - at about four times the price of a CTK1100.

Comment: This is something I've noticed, but what exactly are the "levels" of sensitivity? What does "level" here mean? Isn't it just either it has sensitivity or doesn't?

Comment: Different players prefer different ranges of "key weight." Also, if you have several keyboards stacked up for playing live, you might want to adjust them all to have the same "feel".  (Actually, there is a generally agreed "standard key weight" for acoustic piano keyboards, but different instruments can still feel quite different from each other).

Comment: Indeed. The label 'weighted' is important to be shown, as it trebles the price asked! And - it's worth every penny!

Comment: @alephzero, so for someone who just uses it for playing classics and pop music use (not even going to use any of the digital services), what level should I aim for?

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at a distributor's webside finds:

Natural Weighted Hammer Action Keyboard

Weighted 88-Key Hammer Action Keyboard

Ivory Feel-G Keyboard for Natural, Comfortable Feel

Advanced Hammer Action IV-F

88 Hammer Action Keys
Progressive Hammer Action with Escapement

Continuing to the small print, I THINK all of these are some type of weighted keyboard.  If in doubt ask.  But don't assume the salesman at the end of a phone line knows any more than the brochure says!